# python calculator only adds (if statement dominates other statements)

Tags: python, if-statement, calculator

So I've written some code for a simple calculator that asks for a number, asks for a math operation, asks for a second number, and prints the results. I also added a line to print for an invalid operator input. However, all the code does is  the the first IF line. No matter what I add for the operator the results are for addition. Invalid operator input also results in addition.

The code is the following:

```
\\\
num1 = float(input("Enter first number"))
op = input("What do you want to do?")
num2 = float(input("Enter second number"))
if op == "+":
   print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
   print(num1 - num2)
elif op == "*":
   print(num1 * num2)
elif op == "/":
   print(num1 / num2)
else:
    print("wait a minute! that's not a valid operation dude!")
```

Example output 1:

Enter first number 1
What do you want to do? -
Enter second number 1
2.0

Example output 2
Enter first number 3
What do you want to do? /
Enter second number 3
6.0

Example output 3
Enter first number 6
What do you want to do? sleep
Enter second number 6
12.0

What am I doing wrong? I don't see any errors in PyCharm. Is it indenting? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Above code is working for me as expected

Comment: The code seems to be working fine, you must check your python file if it's similar. Moreover in this case you should use switch case statement, instead of if else!

Comment: @ArooshRana Python has no switch statement...

Comment: Sorry my mistake @brunodesthuilliers, thanks for correcting. I meant implement same thought! One can use dictionary for the same, where keys act like switch argument.